# beginner javascript question

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

This should be easy, but since I'm new to programming, specially in javascript, I cannot figure it out.

Let's say I have the following javascript code:

```
var InjectClientValue = Class.create();


InjectClientValue.prototype = {
    initialize: function( sourceElement, eventElement, updateElement ) {
        this.sourceElement = $(sourceElement);
        this.element = $(eventElement);
        this.updateElement =$(updateElement)
        this.element.observe('click',this.onClick.bindAsEventListener(this));
    },
    onClick: function(event) {
        new Ajax.Request(this.element.href+"/"+this.sourceElement.value, {
            method:'get', 

            onSuccess: function(transport) {

                //How do I access the instance variable updateElement in InjectClientValue_
            //updateElement.update(transport.responseJSON.content);
            }
        });
        event.stop();

    }
    }
```

What I need is to access the variable updateElement setted in initialize from the onSuccess of new Ajax.Request. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onClick: function(event) {
    var thisVariable = this;

    new Ajax.Request(this.element.href+"/"+this.sourceElement.value, {
        method:'get', 

        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            thisVariable.updateElement.update(transport.responseJSON.content);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an instance of the class as "InjectClientValue," you can use that to reference the object and call methods on it.

`onClick: function(event) {
    new Ajax.Request(this.element.href+"/"+this.sourceElement.value, {
        method:'get', 
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
            InjectClientValue.updateElement.update(transport.responseJSON.content);
        }`